# OpenGL: How to resolve the lighting problem of Cube?

Tags: c++, opengl, line, lighting, opengl-compat

[image: Cube image]

```
// Vertices information
GLfloat vertices[] = { 1, 1, 1,  -1, 1, 1,  -1,-1, 1,   1,-1, 1, // (front)
                    1, 1, 1,   1,-1, 1,   1,-1,-1,   1, 1,-1,   // (right)
                    1, 1, 1,   1, 1,-1,  -1, 1,-1,  -1, 1, 1,   // (top)
                   -1, 1, 1,  -1, 1,-1,  -1,-1,-1,  -1,-1, 1,   // (left)
                   -1,-1,-1,   1,-1,-1,   1,-1, 1,  -1,-1, 1,   // (bottom)
                    1,-1,-1,  -1,-1,-1,  -1, 1,-1,   1, 1,-1 }; // (back)

// Normal information
GLfloat normals[72] = { 0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 1,   // (front)
                    1, 0, 0,   1, 0, 0,   1, 0, 0,   1, 0, 0,   // (right)
                    0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,   0, 1, 0,   // (top)
                   -1, 0, 0,  -1, 0, 0,  -1, 0, 0,  -1, 0, 0,   // (left)
                    0,-1, 0,   0,-1, 0,   0,-1, 0,   0,-1, 0,   // (bottom)
                    0, 0,-1,   0, 0,-1,   0, 0,-1,   0, 0,-1 }; // (back)

// drawing cube
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);
glPopMatrix();
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); 
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

I want to make sure there is no color difference between the two sides.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "no color difference"? It's a *cube*; if you are using lighting correctly, then you *will* see a color difference across edges. That color difference is how our eyes know there's an edge there at all.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is causes, because you've activated the flat shading mode (see [Detecting legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) and [`glShadeModel`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glShadeModel.xml)). 
Thus the light is computed for the vertices of the [triangle primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives), but the color of the triangle is determined by the [Provoking vertex](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Provoking_vertex).

Switch to the the smooth (`GL_SMOOTH`) shading model and ensure that the light is diffuse (`GL_DIFFUSE` parameter - see [`glLight`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLight.xml)):

```cpp
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
```

See the difference between shading mode `GL_FLAT` (left) and `GL_SMOOTH` (right):

[image]

---

Another option would be to render `GL_QUADS` primitives instead of `GL_TRIANGLES` primitives:

<s>`glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices)`</s>

```cpp
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
```

Again, `GL_FLAT` (left) and `GL_SMOOTH` (right):

[image]